# @PersistenceContext on two different LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean throws TransactionRequiredException

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, entitymanager

I have two `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`s set up, one with `@Primary` annotation and one without. This is because I have to communicate with two distinct databases, and if I remove the `@Primary` decoration I get a duplicate bean error. Both of them are constructed in the exact same way, here's one for reference:

```
package com.myorg.rest.config.dba;

import ...

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = "com.myorg.rest.dao.dbA",
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "dbAEntityManager",
    transactionManagerRef = "dbATransactionManager"
    )
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DbADataSourceConfig {

    @Autowired
    private EnvProperties settings;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource prjDataSource() {
        DataSourceProperties ds = settings.getdbADatasource();
        return ds.initializeDataSourceBuilder().type(BasicDataSource.class).build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "dbAEntityManager")
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean dbAEntityManager() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(prjDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.myorg.model.entities.dba" });
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("dbAUnit");

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        // em.afterPropertiesSet();

        return em;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dbATransactionManager")
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager dbATransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(dbAEntityManager().getObject());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Both of them are injected inside DAOs with `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "dbAUnit")` and `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "dbBUnit")`, and they are both successfully bootstrapping the corresponding EntityManager inside. I can create in both of them and then retrieve the created entity. But when I go to retrieve all entities with the following:

```
public List<T> findAll() {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> entityQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(clazz);
    entityQuery.from(clazz);
    return entityManager.createQuery(entityQuery).getResultList();
}
```

One of them works flawlessly and the other one doesn't (it returns 0 entities). After debugging, I've realized that one of them was issuing the `insert into...` sql command, while the other one wasn't. I tried to force with `entityManager.flush()` and got

```
 Caused by:
            javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
                at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:413)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeededForUpdateOperation(SessionImpl.java:3398)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1355)
                at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1350)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:366)
                at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.flush(Unknown Source)
```

I then tried to decorate the DAOs with `@Transactional`, and further decorate each individual method with `@Transactional`. Also tried injecting with `@PersistenceContext(unitName = "dbAUnit", type = PersistenceContextType.TRANSACTION)`, but all of those attempts result in the exact same error.

**Why is the 'secondary' `@PersistenceContext` not putting the transactions in?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using multiple transaction managers with `@Transactional`, you need to declare the transaction manager to use explicitly, otherwise the `@Primary` manager always gets selected, and your secondary `EntityManager` cannot possibly join its transaction.

Try using `@Transactional("dbBTransactionManager")` wherever the second persistence context is injected, to see if the problem goes away.

Comment: That's what I needed, thanks. What I don't understand though, is why this doesn't happen automatically if I'm injecting through `@PersistenceContext(unitName = 'nnn')`

Comment: What if you injected both? Also, Spring doesn't understand the relation between a persistence context and a transaction manager

Comment: If I inject both I expect to have two transactions, don't I? And sure, Spring is operating on top of JPA, BUT, it already understands how to deal with it, because in the case of a single DataSource and/or the `@Primary` one, it already works flawlessly! Maybe it is that I just don't understand the basics here, do you have any recommendations on a good course explaining all this?

Comment: Nope, sorry. To be completely honest, I only learned how to deal with multiple `TransactionManager`s by researching your question, and eventually found the answer in the Spring docs, I think

Comment: The thing to take away from this example is really to think of Spring selecting the `TransactionManager` to use with a bare `@Transactional` annotation pretty much the same way the `TransactionManager` bean would be selected if you had `@Autowired TransactionManager manager` somewhere in your code (so, two beans of the same type produce a conflict, if one of them is `@Primary`, that's the one that will be used etc.). `@Transactional("something")`, on the other hand, works like the injection of `@Autowired @Qualifier("something") TransactionManager manager`, resolving the bean conflict

Comment: Yes, I agree that's what's likely going on here. What I can't figure out is why `PersistenceContext(unitName = "whatever")` is not enough. It is qualified, it is not duplicated, and in no way makes use of the `@Primary` annotation, since it is fully qualified. Yet, for whatever the reason, it works for the `@Primary`ed one, and not for the other one.

Comment: It *does* work for the other one. It starts the transaction with the `@Primary` `TransactionManager` as well (because again, without the qualifier that's going to be the one that is always selected), it's just that fact has no effect on your code, because your secondary `EntityManager` cannot join that transaction

Comment: I believe that if you halt your code using the debugger, and call `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()` just before the `TransactionRequiredException` is thrown, it will return `true`. The problem is that's a transaction your code can't use. And `TransactionRequiredException` is coming from Hibernate, not Spring

Comment: And `@Transactional` doesn't know (or care) about `@PersistenceContext`. The code that handles `@Transactional` simply picks **a** `TransactionManager`, uses it to start a transaction, and it's job is pretty much done (until transaction commit, that is). It is then the transactional resource's (`EntityManager`'s) responsibility to join that transaction (if possible) or ignore it

Comment: Just a FYI, I was checking all of this during automatic testing. Turns out that, upon decorating with `@DataJpaTest`, the application was bootstrapping the `@Primary` `TransactionManager`. When I tried it in the "real" context, I had to end up decorating with `@Transactional` both of the services because no transaction was in place. Now I'm a little bit happier :)